# Create table gives error table already exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Table1

```
Col1   Col2     Col3
 1   'Name1' 'Address1'
```

Where `col1` is primary key with constraint `'constraint1'`.

Now i want to rename `Table1` to `Table2`. Add `col1_1` in it and change primary key from 'col1' to `col1_1`

Then create new table with name '`Table1`'

Now i had renamed table Table1 to Table2 and added column 'col1_1' in it as primary key in deployment script.

In pre deployment script:

1: Deleted old primary key constraint.

2: Rename `Table1` to `Table2` using sp_rename

When i publish the database i am getting error '`Table2`' object already exist on Create '`Table2`'

Comment: Can you show the script? It sounds like you don't have a `GO` after the `sp_rename`.

Comment: IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Table1')
 BEGIN
  EXEC sp_rename 'Table1', 'Table2'
 END
GO

Comment: I do have GO after sp_rename

Comment: Any chance Table2 already existed before the rename... You mention pre-deployment script.  If you are testing this out could it be possible this script was already ran and thus table2 does already exist....? OR Is it possible the script is being ran on a schema that already had this script ran on it....?

Comment: @klabranche. Good point, you should also check for `Table2` existing.

Comment: No, if Table2 is already exist then it will give error on rename. But its giving error on create Table2

Comment: Can you post the whole script? That would help us see where this is erroring out.

Comment: IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Table2')
BEGIN
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Table1')
 BEGIN
  EXEC sp_rename 'Table1', 'Table2'
 END
END
GO

Comment: Added check of Table2 exist on rename but still not working.

Comment: The other part(creating table) is done in visual studio sql tool

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143304/discussion-between-hemant-malpote-and-wei-dba).

Comment: what is alternative to  sp_rename

Comment: Though you rename the table name Table1 to Table2 the object ID of both tables are same ,beacuse of that you may get error

Comment: But on creation of table vs checked by default already exist. But in my case it is not working.

Comment: Why are you doing the `Create Table` in visual studio? I tried your scenario in SSMS and it works fine. I'm wondering if VS is not refreshing the database tables or something like that.

Comment: When somebody do fresh deployment, he will need create table and for him rename table will not fired.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SSMS, or if you can get a DBA to check it for you.. then please check first whether an Object with the name Table2 already exists.
You may run the below T-SQLs

```
USE DatabaseName
GO
select * from sysobjects
where name = 'Table2' 
GO
```

In the above query's result set, xtype will denote the object type. You can get a list of object types by running the below query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'O9T'
```